# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. State parameter not saved in database when oauth2 authorization server issues an authorization code to a client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I'm trying to replicate the oauth 2.0 authorization code flow with the following 3 projects, but, as you can see by the title, ***I'm struggling in getting redirected to the client server after I'm successfully authenticated and authorized by the authorization server***.

**Projects description:**

I have implemented an authorization server very similar to the one provided by [Spring Documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/1.1.x/samples/demo-authorizationserver), with the following variations:

1. Maven instead of gradle, as project builder
2. JRE: jdk1.8.0_xxx
3. Spring Boot 2.7.12 , Spring Security 5.7.8 , Spring Security oauth2 authorization server 0.4.2 ,
4. a sql database for user's credentials. Here I also implemented the 3 oauth2 tables that, in the Spring demo, are located in an embedded h2 database,
5. a custom UserDetailsService instead of an InMemoryUserDetailsManager:

   ```
   @Service
   public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

       @Autowired
       UserRepository userRepository;

       @Override
       @Transactional
       public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        User u = user.orElseThrow(() ->
           new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with email : " + email));

           return SecurityUser.create(u);
       }

   }
   ```

   Here the SecurityUser class:

   ```
   public class SecurityUser implements OAuth2User, UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;    
    private String username;   
    private String password;   
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities; 
    private Map<String, Object> attributes;

    public SecurityUser() {}

       public SecurityUser(Long id, String email, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
           this.id = id;
           this.username = email;
           this.password = password;
           this.authorities = authorities;
       }

       public static SecurityUser create(User user) {
         List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Collections.
         singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
           return new SecurityUser(
                   user.getUser_id(),
                   user.getEmail(),
                   user.getPwd(),
                   authorities
           );
       }

       public static SecurityUser create(User user, Map<String, Object> attributes) {
           SecurityUser userPrincipal = SecurityUser.create(user);
           userPrincipal.setAttributes(attributes);

           return userPrincipal;
       }

   // getters and setters

       @Override
       public String toString() {
         return new StringJoiner(", ", SecurityUser.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
             .add("id='" + id + "'")
             .add("username='" + username + "'")
             .add("authorities='" + authorities + "'")
             .add("attributes='" + attributes + "'")
             .toString();
       }
   }
   ```

   Here the SecurityUserMixin class (needed at point n. 7):

   ```
   @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
   @JsonDeserialize
   @JsonAutoDetect(
           fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY,
           getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
           isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
   public class SecurityUserMixin {

    @JsonProperty
    private Long id;    
        @JsonProperty
    private String username;  
        @JsonIgnore 
        private String password;
        @JsonIgnore 
        private String name;
    @JsonProperty
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities; 
        @JsonProperty
    private Map<String, Object> attributes;

         @JsonCreator
         public SecurityUserMixin(@JsonProperty("id") Long id, 
                @JsonProperty("username") String username,
                @JsonProperty("authorities") Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities,
                @JsonProperty("attributes") Map<String, Object> attributes) {}


   // getters and setters

   }
   ```
6. I removed the device flow authentication's logic (as I downgraded the authorization server's version to 0.4.2) from the AuthorizationServerConfig class:

   ```
   @Bean  
   @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
   public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

           OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authzServerConfigurer = new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer();

           RequestMatcher endpointsMatcher = authzServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher();

        Function<OidcUserInfoAuthenticationContext, OidcUserInfo> userInfoMapper = (context) -> { 
            OidcUserInfoAuthenticationToken authentication = context.getAuthentication();
            JwtAuthenticationToken principal = (JwtAuthenticationToken) authentication.getPrincipal();
            return new OidcUserInfo(principal.getToken().getClaims());
        };

           authzServerConfigurer
            .authorizationEndpoint(authzEndpoint -> authzEndpoint
                   .consentPage(CUSTOM_CONSENT_PAGE_URI))
            .oidc(oidc -> oidc
                    .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo
                            .userInfoMapper(userInfoMapper)
                        )
        );

        http
            .requestMatcher(endpointsMatcher)
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .antMatchers(CUSTOM_LOGIN_PAGE_URI).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(endpointsMatcher))
            .exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                    new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(CUSTOM_LOGIN_PAGE_URI),
                    new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                )
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(resourceServer -> resourceServer
                .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()) 
            )
        .apply(authzServerConfigurer); 

        return http.build();
    }
   ```

   As result (and since I applied my own OAuth2TokenCustomizer method), these classes are not included in my project anymore:

   - FederatedIdentityIdTokenCustomizer
   - UserRepositoryOauth2UserHandler
   - DeviceClientAuthenticationProvider
   - DeviceClientAuthenticationToken
   - DeviceController
   - DeviceClientAuthenticationConverter
7. I modified the Oauth2AuthorizationService method since I had to resolve the [issue n. 397](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/397#issuecomment-900148920):

   ```
    @Bean
       public OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate,
                                                              RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
           JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService =
                   new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcTemplate, registeredClientRepository);
           JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.OAuth2AuthorizationRowMapper rowMapper =
                   new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.OAuth2AuthorizationRowMapper(registeredClientRepository);
           JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.OAuth2AuthorizationParametersMapper oAuth2AuthorizationParametersMapper =
                   new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.OAuth2AuthorizationParametersMapper();

           ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
           ClassLoader classLoader = JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.class.getClassLoader();
           List<Module> securityModules = SecurityJackson2Modules.getModules(classLoader);
           objectMapper.registerModules(securityModules);
           objectMapper.registerModule(new OAuth2AuthorizationServerJackson2Module());
           objectMapper.addMixIn(SecurityUser.class, SecurityUserMixin.class);

           rowMapper.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
           oAuth2AuthorizationParametersMapper.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

           authorizationService.setAuthorizationRowMapper(rowMapper);
           authorizationService.setAuthorizationParametersMapper(oAuth2AuthorizationParametersMapper);

           return authorizationService;
           // replace:
   //        return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcTemplate, registeredClientRepository);
       }
   ```

All other classes of the authorization not mentioned are left unchanged from Spring's ones.

Then I implemented a resource server (built with Maven) and a client server (built with Gradle). Both are very similar to those of Spring, but, in the client, I remove device flow authentication logic.

To implement the 3 oauth2 tables I used the default sql scripts for this  authorization server version, but I replaced every blob type column with varchar and every timestamp type column with datetime.

To build the authorization server and the resource server I used this maven build command: spring-boot:run.

**Projects behaviour and error:**

All 3 projects build up correctly, and the registered client configured in my authorization server is saved in the oauth2_registered_client table.

Via browser, I try to access the client server and I'm (correctly) redirected to the authorization server. Here I authenticate with the credentials of a previously registered user, and I'm redirected to the consent page. At this point, if I check the database queries in the project logs, I see an INSERT INTO oauth2_authorization table query, with a STATE value, but, if I check the table on the database, no records are available.

In the consent page, the only consent available is profile and after I select that and submit the form, ***the authorization server goes in a loop where it continues to issue new authorization codes***, one every second, and on the browser I get the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.

In the project's logs (`logging.level.org.springframework.security: TRACE`) I see no errors: after the GET and POST /oauth2/authorize, the POST oauth2/token, the GET /oauth2/jwks and the GET /userinfo requests, the projects starts again to secure the GET /oauth2/authorize with a different authorization code (and state value!) from the same previous GET.

On the network tab on DevTools I see some redirects to ...login/code/messaging-client-oidc with different authorization codes and state values ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHHyi.png)) I stop the loading of the page (as I know that would generate the error I mentioned), and if I check the oauth2_authorization table on my database I see a bunch of records with different authorization codes but everyone with NULL state.

However, If I try to reach one of my resource server endpoints via Postman, the authentication and authorization flow works and I get an access_token after I select the consents required. But still, no state value is saved in the record on the oauth2_authorization table.

Apart from this, if I stopped my authorization server and I plug the Spring one, the authorization flow works perfectly and I'm redirect to the client as expected.

**To sum up, I'm asking you**:

1. Can someone explain me why, if I use the authorization server provided by Spring instead of my custom authorization server everything seems to work correctly, as I get redirect to the client after the login and the consent selection?
2. Did I miss something downgrading the authorization server project to a version of oauth2-authorization-server dependency without the device flow authentication? Beside this change and my own token customizer, I only used a sql database instead of an embedded database, so I don't get why the authorization flow is not completed just with my authorization server.
3. In which class does the authorization server provided by Spring explictly save the state parameter in the oauth2_authorization table? Could it be in the AuthorizationConsentController?
4. Could you please explain how does the "state" and "nonce" checking work in the oauth2 authorization code flow or suggest me where I can find understandable documentation ?

Please, note that citation of sources for each of the answers is very welcome.

Comment: Since the error is on the client, please provide the client logs that indicate what the problem actually is. You are in a redirect loop because the client is generating an error, and seeing the `/error` page requires authentication (hence the loop).

Comment: Thank you @Steve, please see the following link for the logs as I couldn't update the question since logs are too long: https://github.com/lorenzoAgainAgainAgain/springLogs/blob/main/client-logs.txt

Comment: You're getting "OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_user_info_response]". What scopes are you requesting in your `ClientRegistration` on the client side (application.properties/yml)? Also what is your `RegisteredClient` on the authorization server side. You're missing some details in the question on this point. I'd really encourage you to simplify by removing your customizations and getting a working flow first before customizing the things you mention in the question.

Comment: Also, `OidcUserService` throws `invalid_user_info_response` error when the `sub` claim of the `id_token` does not match the `sub` of the user info response. So you almost certainly have a mis-configuration (or are missing configuration for mapping the username).

Comment: Steve, big thanks for your time, **it was exactly the mismatch between the sub of the access_token and the id_token that was causing the problem**. May I ask you where I can found official documentation about this? I've looked for this particular error but I didn't find anything helpful. Also, which attributes between `ClientRegistration` on client side and `RegisteredClient` on authz server side must match? I ask this because I've checked my client and authorization server (as you suggested) and everything was matching except the client name.

Comment: Sorry to bother again @Steve, but I notice that even if now the authorization and redirection flow is working, for every record in the oauth2_authorization table, there's no state value stored. Is this behaviour ok or there should be a state value saved?

Comment: The `state` value is removed after the flow is successful, IIRC.